# Umbraco drop down list with content entered by admin - xpath dropdown?

Tags: umbraco

In Umbraco 6.1, I need to add a field to a Document Type that gets it's possible values from a list that an admin user can add to via the back end.

I figured I'd do this by creating a Developer/Data Type of type XPath DropDownList and have that point to a folder in my Umbraco content through the XPath Expression //Configuration/lookup-lists/course-availability. I've set the Type of Document and Value to Node Id/

This drop down list isn't displaying the SimpleTextItems that are within this folder (its empty).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking to select content from a specific folder in your content-tree, is this correct? Look into the [Multi-Node Tree Picker](http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MultiNodeTreePicker&referringTitle=Documentation) in this case as you can configure this pick 1-n nodes in any specific folder or type..

If the above is not what you're looking for, you might also check the [uComponents dropdown](http://ucomponents.org/data-types/dropdown-checklist/) that an admin with access to the Developer section can edit the 'pre-values'.

Whatever you're looking for exactly - some data type in the [uComponents package](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/ucomponents) is most likely the answer. If not (u'd be surprised!), you may have to code your own .

Comment: Yes, Im looking to select content from a specific folder in my content tree. In the folder are items of type SimpleText. In this is case it's a 1-1 relationship so I assume the XPath DropDownList would do the job but my XPath expression must be wrong (/root/Configuration/lookup-lists/course-availability where course-availability is the folder name)

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is incorrect.

your Xpath should be something like (loads all existing documents with doctype:SimpleText and in first level of Umbraco tree)

```
$ancestorOrSelf/ancestor-or-self::*[@level=1]/SimpleText
```

Please take a look at [here](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/using-umbraco/backoffice-overview/property-editors/Built-in-Property-Editors/XPath-DropDown-List) to see correct Xpath samples for your dropdownlist